# INotifyPropertyChanged not firing on ViewModel inside ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm using `ObservableCollection<MyItemViewModel> myItemVMList` as the `ItemsSouce`. I am able to bind `Command` perfectly but the `INotifyPropertyChanged` isn't working. Here's my code:

```
public class MyItemViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name) {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    public MyItem MyItem { set; get; }

    private RelayCommand _ChangeMyItemPropertyValue;
    public ICommand ChangeMyItemPropertyValueCommand {
        get {
            if (_ChangeMyItemPropertyValue == null) _ChangeMyItemPropertyValue = new RelayCommand(o => ChangeMyItemPropertyValue());
            return _ChangeMyItemPropertyValue;
        }
    }
    private ChangeMyItemPropertyValue() {
        MyItem.SomeProperty = someDifferentValue;

        // NEITHER OF THESE CALLS WORK
        OnPropertyChanged("MyItem.SomeProperty");
        OnPropertyChagned("SomeProperty");
    }
}
```

Needless to say, the binding is set as `Content="{Binding MyItem.SomeProperty}"` inside the `DataTemplate`, and it shows the correct value. Problem is it isn't updated when I run the function.

**SideNote:** If I implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` inside `MyItem` it works, but I want it on the `ViewModel`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` inside `MyItem` it works, but I want it on the `ViewModel`

Yes, because that's how it's designed. How it's supposed to know it should listen to your ViewModel's property changed event? It doesn't bind to it, it binds to the model, so it listens to the changes on the model.

You have two choices basically:

- Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on `MyItem`
- Bind to the `ViewModel`

  ```
  Content="{Binding SomeProperty}"
  ```

  And add a wrapper property:

  ```
  public string SomeProperty
  {
      get { return MyItem.SomeProperty; }
      set
      {
          MyItem.SomeProperty = value;
          OnPropertyChanged("SomeProperty");
      }
  }
  ```

  You should prefer binding to the ViewModel if you want to follow MVVM practices.

---

Side note: If you add `[CallerMemberName]` to `OnPropertyChanged` like this:

```
protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null) {
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
}
```

You'll be able to skip the property name altogether:

```
    public string SomeProperty
    {
        get { return MyItem.SomeProperty; }
        set
        {
            MyItem.SomeProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(); // <-- no need for property name anymore
        }
    }
```

Comment: I understand, so my mistake is that instead of `{Binding MyItem.SomeProperty}` I should have added a wrapper in the VM and bind to that?

Comment: @Christopher exactly. The thing is that when you bind to `Foo.Bar.Baz`, it will listen to change notifications on `Foo` and `Foo.Bar`. In your case, it listens to change notifications on `MyItem`.

Comment: Oohhh I understand, thank you very much; I'm new to .NET (not only to WPF) so I was having trouble understanding how it works internally (articles usually just say how to do it but doesn't explain internal things).

Comment: You're welcome. If you want to better understand how WPF works, I can advise you [this book](http://www.adamnathan.net/wpf/) from one of the WPF's authors.